# combine the same column numbers from 2 files

Tags: r, awk

I have two big files. each file have 1000 columns and 2000 rows. I would like to merge them using a loop (R or linux) so that the same columns numbers come together:

file a:

```
[,1] [,2] ... [,1000]
1    3
1    3
1    4
1    3
1    5
```

file b:

```
[,1] [,2] .... [,1000]
2    7
2    8
2    9
2    10
2    11
```

after merging:

```
[,1] [,1] [,2][,2] .... [,1000][,1000]
1  2  3  7
1  2  3  8
1  2  4  9
1  2  3  10
1  2  5  11
```

Comment: Please don't undo edits that try to make this clear. Your original version doesn't make any sense but the edit @Jilber made is logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple in awk and no need to specify limits or create temp files or....:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {split(a[FNR],b); for (i in b) $i=b[i]" "$i}1' file1 file2
[,1] [,1] [,2] [,2] ... .... [,1000] [,1000]
1 2 3 7
1 2 3 8
1 2 4 9
1 2 3 10
1 2 5 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's another method to use loops with help from Gavin

```
result<-matrix(0,nrow=5,ncol=2000)
t<-0
for (i in 1:(1000)){
  t<-t+1
  result[,(2*t-1)]<-a[,t]
  result[,(2*t)]<-b[,t]
}
```

Comment: I have 1000 columns in each file

Comment: That's a very good reason.  I think that this should do what you want.

Comment: In R, it isn't very efficient to build objects up like you do in a loop. Better to allocate storage and fill in the object whilst looping.

Comment: @Ryan You are clicking the wrong markup button (or using the wrong markup) for code. You want the button that looks like a pair of braces `{}` not the curly quotes one. Or just indent lines by 4 spaces, or select the code block and press ctrl-k

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is `cbind()`. Consider:

```
a <- matrix(c(rep(1, 5),
              3,3,4,3,5), ncol = 2)
b <- matrix(c(rep(2, 5),
              7:11), ncol = 2)

cbind(a, b)
```

Which gives.

```
> cbind(a, b)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    2    7
[2,]    1    3    2    8
[3,]    1    4    2    9
[4,]    1    3    2   10
[5,]    1    5    2   11
```

The objects you show are/look like matrices, but you can do the same operation using data frames.

Subsetting might be useful in the special case where you want to interleave the columns, as per your example

```
ind <- c(rbind(seq_len(ncol(a)), seq_len(ncol(b)) + ncol(a)))
cbind(a, b)[, ind]

> ind <- c(rbind(seq_len(ncol(a)), seq_len(ncol(b)) + ncol(a)))
> cbind(a, b)[, ind]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    7
[2,]    1    2    3    8
[3,]    1    2    4    9
[4,]    1    2    3   10
[5,]    1    2    5   11
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty implementation with `awk` and `paste`:

```
#!/bin/bash

infile_a=a
infile_b=b
output_file=outfile
temp_a=tempa
temp_b=tempb
temp_out=tempout

if [[ -e $output_file ]]; then
    rm $output_file
fi

touch $output_file

total_col=1000
cur_col=1

while [[ $cur_col -le $total_col ]]
do
    awk -v col=$cur_col '{print $(col)}' $infile_a > $temp_a
    awk -v col=$cur_col '{print $(col)}' $infile_b > $temp_b
    paste $output_file $temp_a $temp_b > $temp_out
    mv $temp_out $output_file
    cur_col=$((cur_col+1))
done
```

Comment: have 1000 columns in each file, so I need a loop

Answer (score 0):

Another quick and dirty alternative with paste and awk:

`paste a b|awk 'BEGIN{cols=1000;} {line = ""; for(i=1; i<=cols; ++i) {line = line $i FS $(i + cols) FS;} print line;}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  {
    getline line < "fileb"
    split(line, ary)
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf("%s%s%s%s", $i, OFS, ary[i], OFS)
    }
    print ""
  }
' filea
```

Comment: just be aware that will add a trailing OFS to the end of every line. There's various ways around that of course...